# Merge two dataframes by partial string match

Tags: python, r

I am trying to merge two fairly large dataframes of different sizes based on partial string matches.

df1$code contains all 12 digit codes, while df2$code contains a mix of codes with 10-12 digits, where some of the shorter codes are substring matches to the 12 digit codes in df1$code.

Therefore, I need to merge all 12 digit matches between the two dataframes, but also those records in df2 that have 10-11 digit codes that are substring matches to the df1.

Example dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(code_1 = c('123456789012', '210987654321', '567890543211', '987656789001', '123456654321', '678905432156', '768927461037', '780125634701', '673940175372', '167438501473'),
              name = c('bob','joe','sally','john','lucy','alan', 'fred','stephanie','greg','tom'))

df2 <- data.frame(code_2 = c('123456789012','2109876543','7890543211','98765678900','12345665432','678905432156'),
              color = c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown'))

df3 (merged)

code_1         code_2         name  color
123456789012   123456789012   bob   blue
210987654321   2109876543     joe   red
567890543211   7890543211     sally green
987656789001   98765678900    john  purple
123456654321   12345665432    lucy  orange
678905432156   678905432156   alan  brown
```

Comment: Can we simply truncate every code to 10 digits in length, and match on that?

Comment: Do you want python solution too? You originally included a python tag before someone else edited it out.

Comment: shouldn't `'7890543211'` match `'567890543211'`? or do you only care about substrings that occur at the start of the 12 digits?

Comment: @useR if your example is the desired result, you can use `sapply(df1$code, agrep, df2$code,value=TRUE)` to get the matching values. I don't know how to get back from the list to the join though.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the fields. I can't truncate to 10 digits because some are missing digits from the beginning and some the end (some missing a single digit from both beginning and end). And I can use either R or Python answers. Thanks!

Comment: @vethno I updated my answer and I think it should catch all cases now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this SQL join.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.code_1, b.code_2, a.name, b.color 
       from df2 b left join df1 a on a.code_1 like '%' || b.code_2 || '%'")
```

giving:

```
        code_1       code_2  name  color
1 123456789012 123456789012   bob   blue
2 210987654321   2109876543   joe    red
3 567890543211   7890543211 sally  green
4 987656789001  98765678900  john purple
5 123456654321  12345665432  lucy orange
6 678905432156 678905432156  alan  brown
```

**Update:** Updated answer to reflect change in question so that (1) the substring can be anywhere in the target string and (2) names of code columns have changed to `code_1` and `code_2`.

Answer (score 1):

In python/pandas, you can do:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
df1 = DataFrame(dict(
        code1 = ('123456789012', '210987654321', '567890543211', '987656789001', '123456654321', '678905432156', '768927461037', '780125634701', '673940175372', '167438501473'),
        name = ('bob','joe','sally','john','lucy','alan', 'fred','stephanie','greg','tom')))

df2 = DataFrame(dict(
        code2 = ('123456789012','2109876543','7890543211','98765678900','12345665432','678905432156'),
        color = ('blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown')))

matches = [df1[df1['code1'].str.contains(x)].index[0] for x in df2['code2']]

print(
    df1.assign(subcode=Series(data=df2['code2'], index=matches))
       .merge(df2, left_on='subcode', right_on='code2')
       .drop('subcode', axis='columns')
)
```

And that dumps:

```
          code1   name         code2   color
0  123456789012    bob  123456789012    blue
1  210987654321    joe    2109876543     red
2  567890543211  sally    7890543211   green
3  987656789001   john   98765678900  purple
4  123456654321   lucy   12345665432  orange
5  678905432156   alan  678905432156   brown
```

Note: I *hate* using loops with dataframes, but this, uh, works, I guess.

Comment: He asked for an R solution

Comment: @Mako212 and the question isn't that explicit. Considering the OP included a python tag and someone else removed it, I feel this is still a valid answer.

Comment: @Mako212 probably worth removing these comments as the OP has now been explicit in stating that Python solutions are also sought

Comment: @Paul H. Hi, I am trying to use your code now to do this on my dataset but I get the following error: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @mkheifetz impossible to say anything other than, "this solution isn't appropriate for the data that I imagine you have"

Comment: @Paul H. And why do you think that is the case?

Comment: @mkheifetz because I have no idea what your data look like

Comment: @Paul H. It's basically Sentences. Both columns have paragraphs, one of them columns has subsets of the other column's sentences (the two columns are different in size). So let's say column 1 in dataframe 1 has values like "Hello, today is a great day!" and "You did an amazing job" the other column will be values that are subsets of these sentences like "Hello, today" or "You did an" and I want all in the 2nd column (aka the subset) to be joined against the thing they are a proper subset of. Does that kind of make sense?

Comment: Not really. I recommend you boil it down to a simple example and create a new question asking about the specific issues you're having. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i got this error after i run matches do you know why? `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Answer (score 1):

Updated per new info. This should work:

```
df2$New <- lapply(df2$code_2, grep, df1$code_1,value=T)

combined <- merge(df1,df2, by.x="code_1", by.y="New")

        code_1  name       code_2  color
1 123456654321  lucy  12345665432 orange
2 123456789012   bob 123456789012   blue
3 210987654321   joe   2109876543    red
4 567890543211 sally   7890543211  green
5 678905432156  alan 678905432156  brown
6 987656789001  john  98765678900 purple
```

Comment: I don't think this works, since not all 10 digit codes in `df2` matches the _first_ 10 digits in `df1`

Comment: @useR Correct that it doesn't work if the substring starts somewhere within the number, but looking at OPs example, he's just returning 5 matches, which are where the first 10 digits match.

Comment: Note that after my update the above comment is no longer an issue.

Comment: I tried this, but with the full dataframes (one 210K+ rows and the other 30K+ rows, it kept crashing R. Splitting up the 201K+ dataframe into four chunks yielded the following error on the first chunk:  Error in order(list("899349002062", "793573098023", "815036020027", "857638004289",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` + `sapply` to extract indices of matches from `df2$code` for each `df1$code` and create a `matchID` out of it. Next, we `merge` on `matchID` to get desired output:

```
df1$matchID = row.names(df1)
df2$matchID = sapply(df2$code, function(x) grep(x, df1$code))

df_merge = merge(df1, df2, by = "matchID")[-1]
```

Note that if a `df1$code` does not match any `df2$code`, `df2$matchID` will be blank, and so would not merge with `df1$matchID`.

**Results:**

```
> df2
          code  color matchID
1 123456789012   blue       1
2   2109876543    red       2
3   7890543211  green       3
4  98765678900 purple       4
5  12345665432 orange       5
6 678905432156  brown       6
7  14124124124  black        

> df_merge
        code.x  name       code.y  color
1 123456789012   bob 123456789012   blue
2 210987654321   joe   2109876543    red
3 567890543211 sally   7890543211  green
4 987656789001  john  98765678900 purple
5 123456654321  lucy  12345665432 orange
6 678905432156  alan 678905432156  brown
```

**Data (Added non-match for better demo):**

```
df1 <- data.frame(code = c('123456789012', '210987654321', '567890543211', '987656789001', '123456654321', '678905432156', '768927461037', '780125634701', '673940175372', '167438501473'),
                  name = c('bob','joe','sally','john','lucy','alan', 'fred','stephanie','greg','tom'),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(code = c('123456789012','2109876543','7890543211','98765678900','12345665432','678905432156', '14124124124'),
                  color = c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown', 'black'),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```